# Does google cloud VM has any unique id for identificaiton purpose?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am working on application licensing part. As of we have a unique ID for VM's in AZURE and EC2 but I didn't see such ID for google cloud instances.

Is there any such ID available in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud instances do have a unique ID that is assigned on creation by default.

> Relative to
> http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/
>
> id    The ID
> of the instance. This is a unique, numerical ID that is generated by
> Google Compute Engine. This is useful for identifying instances if you
> do not want to use instance names.

There are several ways of getting that metadata. From within an instance you can simply do:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

And that will return the unique numerical ID for that instance. For more detailed information on querying the metadata see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#endpoints)

Comment: thanks jordi,

But, does this ID will be unique in all projects in google cloud or will be unique to related to that current project only?

Comment: The id is unique in all Google Cloud, it's globally unique.